# For a django model field with choices, how to efficiently get a list of the choices that are used in the database?

Tags: django

I'm only a brown-belt at django query-fu.  So maybe there's some new tricks I don't know about here.

Here's my model:

```
SCHOOL_TYPES = (('elementary', 'Elementary Schools'), ('middle', 'Middle Schools'), ('junior_high', 'Junior High Schools'), ('high_school', 'High Schools'), ('other', "Other"))

class School (BaseSlugModel):
    name=CharField(max_length=100)
    school_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SCHOOL_TYPES)
```

For UI purposes, I want to write a function `get_active_school_types` that returns a subset of the SCHOOL_TYPES tuples that have 1 or more schools in them.  Is there a more efficient way to do this than a brute-force, *get all schools and then loop through them* method?

EDIT: Here's my solution, based on Simeon's answer:

```
active_types = School.objects.values_list('school_type', flat=True).distinct()
return [ school_type for school_type in SCHOOL_TYPES if school_type[0] in active_types]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) method of a QuerySet:

```
School.objects.order_by('school_type').distinct('school_type')
```

This will let the database handle it instead of your Python code. Note that passing a field name to `distinct` only works if you're using PostgreSQL.

You can also use [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list):

```
School.objects.values_list('school_type', flat=True).distinct()
```

This will return a list of the values.

Comment: Cool.  I was wondering when I'd find something that would make me wish we were on Django 1.4!  As soon as django-grappelli releases 2.4, I'll be on this.

Comment: @BenR: I've added a different way of doing it that should not require upgrading.

Comment: that works.  I updated my answer with the full solution. I love python! Thanks!